# Can't Get The matlabpool Started

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, matlabpool

I'm running MATLAB on since about one and a half year now. And I've been trying to get *matlabpool* ready to go once in nearly every three months. Before I give up on it completely, I've decided to ask for help. :)

My problem starts with *matlabpool* command. Whenever I type in the *matlabpool* command, I get this :

```
One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "system_dependent".

Error in matlabpool>iIsOnClient (line 73)
onclient = ~system_dependent('isdmlworker');

Error in matlabpool>iVerifyJava (line 64)
if iIsOnClient()

Error in matlabpool (line 10)
iVerifyJava();
```

After some research and sleepless nights, I've found out that one has to settle the things down with the **"Cluster Profile Manager"**. But I never did have the opportunity to see it working either. Here is what I get after clicking **Cluster Profile Manager** from **Parallel** panel :

```
com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabException: Feature isdmlworker not found
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.SendMatlabMessage(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.sendMatlabMessage(NativeMatlab.java:266)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabLooper.sendMatlabMessage(MatlabLooper.java:120)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.Matlab.mtFeval(Matlab.java:1710)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker.feval(MatlabWorker.java:197)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.distcomp.ui.profile.model.MatlabProfileManager$1.runOnMatlabThread(MatlabProfileManager.java:80)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker$2.run(MatlabWorker.java:79)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.dispatchMTRequests(NativeMatlab.java:475)
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in parallel.internal.ui.AbstractValidationManager (line 20)
            obj.Validator.addlistener('ValidationStarted', ...

Error in parallel.internal.ui.ValidationManager (line 21)
            obj@parallel.internal.ui.AbstractValidationManager();

com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabException: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.SendMatlabMessage(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.sendMatlabMessage(NativeMatlab.java:266)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabLooper.sendMatlabMessage(MatlabLooper.java:120)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.Matlab.mtFevalConsoleOutput(Matlab.java:1778)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker.feval(MatlabWorker.java:195)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker.feval(MatlabWorker.java:172)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.distcomp.ui.profile.model.ValidationManager$1.runOnMatlabThread(ValidationManager.java:45)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker$2.run(MatlabWorker.java:79)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.dispatchMTRequests(NativeMatlab.java:475)
```

After getting this message, the **Cluster Profile Manager** pops up, but doesn't really shows anything besides "wait" sign. I've checked my **Distributed Computing Licence** and that too is looking fine.

```
license checkout Distrib_Computing_Toolbox
```

command returns 1.

By the way, there is another error message which I suspected to have a connection with my problem of some kind. I get this in every MATLAB start:

```
Error using feature
Feature isdmlworker not found

Error in matlabrc (line 187)
if ~(ismcc || isdeployed || feature('isdmlworker')) && usejava('jvm')
```

In addition to all of those; I get this message whenever I try to open "Parallel Preferences" from **Environment** tab :

```
com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabException: Feature isdmlworker not found
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.SendMatlabMessage(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.sendMatlabMessage(NativeMatlab.java:265)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabLooper.sendMatlabMessage(MatlabLooper.java:120)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.Matlab.mtFeval(Matlab.java:1619)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker.feval(MatlabWorker.java:197)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.distcomp.ui.profile.model.MatlabProfileManager$1.runOnMatlabThread(MatlabProfileManager.java:72)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabWorker$2.run(MatlabWorker.java:79)
    at com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.dispatchMTRequests(NativeMatlab.java:440)
```

I've tried to find the function **system_dependent.m** but it doesn't seem to exist. Other common spots of the errors I get, the function **"feature.m"**, the option **"isdmlworker"** are other mysteries that I couldn't find any kind of information about.

I really appreciate if anyone can help me with the problem I've encountered starting MATLAB's distributed computing system.

Edit: I'm working on an Ubuntu 14.04 and my MATLAB version is R2014a.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? If `feature('isdmlworker')` isn't there, there's something *seriously* wrong with your installation...

Comment: Added the information that you've requested sir. Do you think that replacing the missing part would do it?

Comment: I have the license for the DCT as well, but not the `isdmlworker` feature either. I can launch the `matlabpool` however, on Windows 7 64bit R2012a

Comment: Can you try restoring your default `PATH` with `restoredefaultpath`? If you want to keep your current path you should save it beforehand.

Comment: `feature` and `system_dependent` are both implemented deep in the guts of MATLAB. There can be some weirdness when using the `feature` version, but if the `system_dependent` version isn't working right - well, I'm stumped (and I can see the source code for this...). I suggest you contact MathWorks support - maybe they've seen this before.

Comment: @Edric `system_dependent('isdlmworker')` nor `system_dependent 'isdlmworker'`  doesn't return anything, not even `ans = 0` or a syntax error. Should I call it differently?

Comment: @IKavanagh I did that before. I even tried reinstalling it a couple of times to be honest. :)

Comment: I just tested this on R2014a and Ubuntu 15.04. `matlabpool` starts without issue.

Comment: @IKavanagh maybe i should do the same.

Comment: Maybe. It sounds like an issue with your specific installation than a MATLAB issue.

Comment: @IKavanagh i did the something relevant to yours. Tried R2014a on 15.10, and voila. I guess it was all because of my Ubuntu installation. I think you deserve the bounty. :)

Comment: @3yanlis1bos I'm glad you've got it working and thank you for offering me the bounty. I've posted an answer with as much information as I can glean from the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with your specific installation of Ubuntu 14.04. It is possible though that it relates to how `matlabpool` spawns worker threads in R2014a given that the error occurs in `com.mathworks.jmi.NativeMatlab.dispatchMTRequests()`.

`matlabpool` has been tested to work without issue on Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10. It may not be an ideal solution but upgrading Ubuntu to 15.04 or 15.10 and reinstalling MATLAB R2014a should resolve the issue.